# Nginx with PHP is functioning correctly but then it stops working

Tags: php, batch-file, nginx

I'm on Windows 8.1 64 bits, PHP 5.6.12 VC11 x64 Thread Safe, nginx 1.9.3. I configured nginx with PHP the way I wanted too (I'm still learning) and I ran it. I opened index.php and it worked, the page displayed correctly. Then I closed the server, opened it again and it stopped working, it sent me the error page instead. This has happened before.

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    include      fastcgi.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  2;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root html;
        index index.php;

        #charset koi8-r;
        access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
          try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        location ~* \.php$ {
          root           html;
          fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
          fastcgi_index  index.php;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME c:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
          include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }

}
```

Here are the start bat script and js (I run the js):

JS:

```
var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var result = objShell.Run("cmd.exe /c start-nginx.bat", 0);

// Give some startup time
WScript.Sleep(3000);

// Navigate to homepage
objShell.Run("http://localhost");
```

BAT:

```
@ECHO OFF
c:\nginx\nginx.exe
c:\nginx\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\nginx\php\php.ini
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1>NUL
echo Starting nginx
echo .
echo .
echo .
ping 127.0.0.1 >NUL
EXIT
```

Here are the stop bat and js (I run the JS too):

JS:

```
var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
var result = objShell.Run("cmd.exe /c stop-nginx.bat", 0)
```

BAT:

```
@ECHO OFF
taskkill /f /IM nginx.exe
taskkill /f /IM php-cgi.exe
EXIT
```

Comment: What was the error message exactly?

Comment: @wOxxOm It's the default server error (html) page from nginx. I'm not the in right pc right now but it says something like "An error has occurred", nothing specific.